# PS: Insert variable output into html file

Tags: html, powershell

I've been trying to insert a variable content into html but the end result is not what I'm looking for.

I have a variable created like this:

```
$FSContent =(get-content .\thisfile.csv) -join "`n" 
$FSContent
```

It imports the file content and create one new line per line in the csv, which has hundreds of lines. 
If I call the $FSContent in the console, it outputs it as required:
Item1 
Item2 
Item3 
....

But when I push this into a htm file, the end of line is skipped and every item is listed one after the other, in one single line.
The code I use is:

```
$HTMLBody = Get-Content $HtmlBodyFile
$HTMLBody = $HTMLBody -replace "%array1%",$FSContent
```

This results in the items showing one after the other: 
item1 item2 item3...

The end of line not being the same in PS & html is probably the reason why it fails but I've tried with convertto-html, doesn't work. Tried to manually replace '(backtick)n' with a line break (br) but doesn't work.
Please note the I'm still fairly new to PS and might have not tried to proper syntax during my tries so I remain open-minded :)

Comment: HTML doesn't care about literal line breaks in source code. Do `(get-content .\thisfile.csv) -join "<br />"` instead

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen thanks, that was that easy :)